# Cron error with Python script

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script that I would like to run in every hour.
The cron command look like this:

54 *    * * *   root    python /home/pi/moka/olx_multi.py 2>&1

The script is not running and I always get the same error without any information about the error real reason.
The error message look like this:

Feb 22 19:54:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[30216]: (root) CMD (python /home/pi/moka/olx_multi.py 2>&1)
Feb 22 19:54:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[30215]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The script is probably running. Just the output (stdout and redirected stderr) are discarded as cron is not attached to any shell - no where to output to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Install an MTA and receive all script output in the user's e-mail address: `sudo apt-get install postfix`. By default the mail will be delivered to a local mailbox in /var/spool/mail/[username]
- Replace `2>&1` by `>/dev/null 2>&1` to ignore the script output
- Append `| logger` to send all script output to syslog

Answer (score 1):

Does you script work when running manually? If yes, I think you should specify full path to python interpreter:

```
54 * * * * root /usr/bin/python /home/pi/moka/olx_multi.py 2>&1
```